# how to call javascript funciton within php

Tags: php, jquery

Looking for ideas & suggestions, I'd like to make a very simple slideshow by pulling the images from a file.

The problems are

(1) There are over 550 images I would like to display in sequence, and do not want to code for that many images... the images are simply numbered 1,2,3,...348,...469... and can be pooled in one folder.

(2) We are constantly adding new images to these folders & would like the slideshow to add them automatically as well.
 I'm trying to call a javascript function within php. it works php but doesnt excute code java script and    here is both scritp php and jquery ..pictures are loaded into website but doesnt show and animate write or left . except first picture .

```
<div class="gallwrapper" >
    <div class="gallmask">
        <ul class="gallul">
         <?php if( is_array($images )): ?>
            <?php foreach($images as $key => $value ): ?> 
               <?php if($value !="." && $value !=".."):?>
                <li class="gallli">
                    <img class="gallimg" src ="gallary/<?php echo $value ?>"   />
                </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
               <?php endif; ?>

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
     <div class="btnleft" >
   <div class="leftbtn-inner" style =" background-image:url('right.png');background-  size: 35px 80px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" >  

   </div>
</div>
<div class="btnright" >
   <div class="rightbtn-inner"  style =" background-image:url('left.png');background-size: 35px 80px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"> </div>  
</div>
```

and this is javascript

```
 var numImages =0;
 var curentImages=1;
var totalwidth=0;
 $(document).ready ( function(){
 $('.gallli').each(function(){
     numImages++;
     totalwidth += 600;
 });
 $('.gallul').css('width' totalwidth + 'px');
 $('.btnright').click (function() {
     moveRight();

 } );
 $('.btnleft').click (function() {
     moveLeft();

 } );
  });
 moveRight() {
 if( curentImages >1) 
 $('.gallul').animate( {'marginLeft' :'-=600px'} , 1000,'swing');
 curentImages--;

 }
   moveLeft() {
   if( curentImages >1) 
 $('.gallul').animate( {'marginLeft' :'+=600px'} , 1000,'swing');
 curentImages++;
 }
```

Comment: It seems you don't understand how it actually works. PHP is sever-side, which means it's executed on the server. Javascript is client-side which, as you can guess, is executed on client which is a browser.

Comment: You need to write a port in PHP for th JS function, or if you wish to use JS on server, write you code in node using express.

Comment: Shouvik 
 what do u mean ( port in PHP for th JS function, )?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibly way to execute native javascript functions. You have to use this extension. Of course it's only a language without DOM API. I'll not recommend to use it in this case.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php.